# formatting Date in rstudio

Tags: r, date

I want to change Date from character into Date, in format ddmmyyyy on rstudio

I tried:

```
base$DATA <- lubridate::dmy(base$DATA)
base$DATA <-   strftime(base$DATA, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Please share some example data (e.g. by pasting the output of `dput`) so that we can better help you, thanks!

Comment: If your date format doesn't have dashes, don't include dashes in the format string: `"%d%m%Y"` will work for, e.g., "25042022", `"%d-%m-%Y"` would work for "25-04-2022", `"%d/%m/%Y"` would work for "25/04/2022", etc.

Comment: But `dmy()` should work regardless of separator, so without sample data it's not clear why you're using `strftime` at all...

Comment: thanks guys, trying to figure out how to sample the data... just a sec

Comment: structure(list(DATA = c("02/03/2022", "02/03/2022"), HORA = c(11L, 
11L), TIPO.PA = c("HUMANO", "HUMANO"), TIPO.PESSOA = c("B2B", 
"B2B"), AGENTE = c("", ""), FILA = c(6025L, 6025L), ALO = c(0L, 
0L), CPC = c(0L, 0L), CPCA = c(0L, 0L), PP = c(0L, 0L), ALEGA = c(0L, 
0L), DESCONHECE = c(0L, 0L), VALOR.... = c(0, 0), DISCAGENS = c(64L, 
51L), AGING = c("> 1 anos", "> 2 anos"), TIKET.MÉDIO = c("1805,85", 
"2011,05"), DIA_DA_SEMANA = c("QUA", "QUA"), DIA_ÚTIL = c(2L, 
2L), X = c(NA, NA), DIA = c("01/03/2022", "02/03/2022"), Dia.da.Semena = 1:2), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")